# Why search results different on sharepoint.aspx and results.aspx?

Tags: sharepoint-online, search

when i searching on xxxx.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/sharepoint.aspx with keyword 'Standalone Non-COPIF' then return expect result . This is the document i need "
Standalone NON-COPIF BTS Licence Agmt Template (21 January 2019)_Final"
[image]

but when i searching on xxx.sharepoint.com/search/Pages/results.aspx it's not return expect result . i haven't found document " Standalone NON-COPIF BTS Licence Agmt Template (21 January 2019)_Final"
[image]

My question is: why are the results of these two pages different?
Would you please give me articles or explanations to help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have re-indexing document library and re-indexing site . And now i have found the document.

The re-indexing process takes about a few days

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Online classic search experience and modern search experience use the same search index to find results.

If we use the same account in both search experience, it will return the same results.

I notice that the URL "k=Template%20for%20…" in result.aspx page is different from “"q=Standalone..." in SharePoint.aspx page, try to scroll to the end of SharePoint.aspx page, click “Go to classic results page” and check again.

Comment: Oops. Sorry, i have updated my topic. Please help me re-checking.. I uploaded the wrong image number 2.

My problem is not finding the document named "Standalone NON-COPIF BTS Licence Agmt Template (21 January 2019)_Final" in result.aspx page

Comment: Whether crawl process lack this document?